# Eric Matthes15.3.3Random walk,Why RandowWalk Class has no attribute x_values

Tags: python

I was creating Randomwalk class,but why does Randomwalk has no atrribute to y

```py
class RandomWalk():    
    def __int__(self,num_ponits=5000,x_values=[0],y_values=[0]):
        self.num_points=num_points
        self.x=x_values
        self.y=y_values
```

the method is like this

```py
def fill_walk(self):
    while len(self.y)<self.num_points:
        x_direction=choice([1,-1])
```

> AttributeError: 'RandomWalk' object has no attribute 'y'

Comment: AttributeError: 'RandomWalk' object has no attribute 'y'

Comment: Did you mean ` __init__` (constructor) instead of ` __int__` (conversion to an integer)?